# Could not create path to save downloaded file: You don’t have permission to save the file “folderName” in the folder “Documents”

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3, file-transfer, download

I am downloading the file from the server in ionic via "Cordova-file-transfer" plugin. It works fine but when I kill app when downloading is in progress, then I reopen I start downloading, sometimes it gives "Could not create path to save downloaded file: You don’t have permission to save the file  “folderName” in the folder “Documents”." error.

It's random issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the error. It has occurred when I update my app when any of the downloads are in the progress.

The solution for it. Create a file(mp3 file) again when the app restarts.